# Extracting data from text file by specific characters

Tags: linux, sed, awk, text-formatting

I have a program that reads from a sensor and prints on stdout. The interesting data for me is just the X,Y and Z values:

```
[2021-05-07 10:47:41.993] [info] Acceleromter (avrg 100): X=+6696.080 Y=-5577.230 Z=-5813.550
[2021-05-07 10:47:42.249] [info] Acceleromter (avrg 100): X=+6692.000 Y=-5580.190 Z=-5808.080
[2021-05-07 10:47:42.506] [info] Acceleromter (avrg 100): X=+6694.200 Y=-5582.050 Z=-5811.460
[2021-05-07 10:47:42.763] [info] Acceleromter (avrg 100): X=+6690.390 Y=-5578.800 Z=-5812.100
[2021-05-07 10:47:43.020] [info] Acceleromter (avrg 100): X=+6691.930 Y=-5580.140 Z=-5808.930
[2021-05-07 10:47:43.277] [info] Acceleromter (avrg 100): X=+6693.400 Y=-5578.180 Z=-5805.930
```

I redirect the output to a file:

```
$program >> data.txt
```

Now I want to extract it to another file like this:

```
+6693.400 -5578.18 -5805.930
```

That is simply values of X, Y and Z with either space or tab as delimiter.

I tried with cut, awk and some other things but I absolutly have no idea what am I doing... I am just bad with these stuff. any help would be great.

Comment: I can think of `grep -Po 'X=[+-][0-9]*\.[0-9]* Y=[+-][0-9]*\.[0-9]* Z=[+-][0-9]*\.[0-9]*' | sed 's/[XYZ]=//g'`

Answer (score 1):

I assume spaces (or tabs) and `=` characters cannot appear "randomly" and therefore they are good separators. If so then this `awk` command will work:

```
awk -F '[\t =]' '{print $8 OFS $10 OFS $12}'
```

The default `OFS` is space. In this form the processing is purely textual, so from `-5578.180` you get `-5578.180`, not `-5578.18`.

<sup>(There are ways to get rid of trailing zeros. Your desired output omits a trailing zero in the second value (Y) but not in other values, so I'm not sure if you really want this. I'm [keeping the answer simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).)</sup>

Use the `awk` command like this: `program | awk …`; or like this: `<data.txt awk …`.

Answer (score 0):

With Gawk :

```
awk -F'[XYZ]=' '{print $2 $3 $4}' data.txt
```

here FS is X=, Y= or Z=.
assume they can't been in the first part of the data.

With sed :

```
sed -E 's/.*((.=.*){3})/\1/;s/.=//g' data.txt
```

first keep only the X=..., Y=...
after that, keep only the data.